# Where are Empathy's contact-links stored?

Tags: configuration, empathy, contacts

I *linked* a bunch of contacts from MSN and Google Talk with the new empathy feature, Now I want to export this configuration to my desktop so i don't have to make the same changes again and again.

Does anyone know where this contact-linking configuration is stored? I didn't find it under `~/.config`, `~/.local/share` or `~/.mission-control`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the links are in `~/.local/share/folks/relationships.ini`

An empathy developer just answered me on [his blog](http://treitter.livejournal.com/12309.html?view=48917).